# Garage door needs light switch on to operate

Tags: electrical, garage-door-opener

I just bought a house.  To use my garage door I just flip the light switch on(in photos)  but this also turns on the lights as well.  So to have my garage door always enabled I would have to leave the lights on all the time.  My question is, would it be okay to just remove the light bulbs and leave the switch on? The main light (orange cord) goes all the way to the circuit breaker, which is in my neighbor's backyard (stupid, HOA design).  The other light looks like it just plugs right into the outlet.  I can't reach any of these.  Just want to know if it's safe to just leave these bulbs out.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem leaving the socket empty, if it cannot be reached and there's no chance of critters getting into it. However, it would be more convenient to have light when you need it. There are [motion-sensing LED lamps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C27D6B9) for less than US$5/each that screw into standard Edison-base sockets, which seem to be what your photo show. The lamps turn on when you go past, and turn off a short time after motion ceases. Look in local stores; I've purchased some for less than $US3.

Answer (score 1):

Code prohibits having *no lights* in a room.  However, several things are allowed.

- Lights that are hardwired on 24x7.  I am doing this more and more because 3-watt LED bulbs are such an inconsequential load.  (At typicaly US power prices, 1 watt 24x7 = $1/year).
- Lights that are on motion sensors, assuming the motion sensors are competent.

So the simplest answer is fit one of these, and then buy any of a variety of plates that attach to your faceplate to either lock or "encourage" the switch to be on 24x7.

Honestly, if it were me, I would have a field day tidying up the mad spiderweb of Romex spammed all over that ceiling, not only so it looks presentable (NEC 110.12 "neat and workmanlike"), but to adapt the wiring to the way I want it.